# How do I check date time is in order with missing date times in data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame with 4 columns containing some zero int values and some date times.  I want to create a new column with a True/False value to tell me if the date times are in  chronological order even though some are 0.

example df

```
P1.   P2.   P3.   P4. 
0.    2011.  0.   2015
2015. 0.    0.    2013
```

I then want to make a new column that just has a T/F depending on if it is in chronological order e.g. in the case above row 1 is true and row 2 is false.

I have considered a loop with if and else but was wondering if there is a cleaner way.  FYI the dates are in the full format 2014-11-31 00:00:00.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Source DF:**

```
In [250]: x
Out[250]:
      P1.     P2.  P3.   P4.
0     0.0  2011.0  0.0  2015
1  2015.0     0.0  0.0  2013
```

**Solution:**

```
In [251]: x['new'] = x[x!=0].apply(lambda x: x.dropna().is_monotonic, axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
In [252]: x
Out[252]:
      P1.     P2.  P3.   P4.    new
0     0.0  2011.0  0.0  2015   True
1  2015.0     0.0  0.0  2013  False
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method following the logic:

- Use `apply` method to loop through rows *axis = 1*;
- For each row, remove zeros, calculate the difference and compare with zeros;
- If none of the difference is smaller than zero, then you can claim that it is in chronological order (ascending);

Plus, if the row contains zero or one valid date (non zero), this logic gives true:

```
df.apply(lambda r: ~(r[r != 0].diff() < 0).any(), 1)

#0     True
#1    False
#dtype: bool
```

Comment: looks like a good answer, but that's really dense... can you unpack that a tad? maybe some comments?

Comment: @JDLong Added the comments.